# Как с помощью скрипта добавить класс первому слову в абзаце?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Как с помощью скрипта добавить класс первому слову в абзаце?

```html
<p>Спорт приносит большую радость. Люди ходят в секции, посещают спорт – клубы, играют в спортивные игры, закаляются и общаются с новыми людьми. Спортивные командные игры приносят радость победы.</p>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если абзац начинается с целого слова (не с предлога или вводного), то достаточно простого регулярного выражения:

```js
let p = document.querySelector('p');
p.innerHTML = p.innerText.replace(/^([а-я]+)/gi, '<span class="first">$1</span>');
```

```css
.first {color: red;}
```

```html
<p>Спорт приносит большую радость. Люди ходят в секции, посещают спорт – клубы, играют в спортивные игры, закаляются и общаются с новыми людьми. Спортивные командные игры приносят радость победы.</p>
```

Comment: В регулярку можно еще добавить учет возможного пробела в самом начале: `/^(\s*?[^\s]+)/`

Comment: @Deonis: пробелы нужно триммить отдельно и заранее.

Comment: Слово "*нужно*", в данном контексте, как-то не очень уместно. Я думаю, что это уже пусть ТС решает: должен быть пробел, может он там быть или его надо триммить. А "первое слово" должно оставаться таковым, вне зависимости от этого возможного фактора. И еще, в вашей регулярке не учитываются слова, которые пишутся через дефис: `как-то`, `где-то`, `плащ-палатка` и т.д.

Comment: @Deonis: видите же, что ТС не плюсует и не принимает мой ответ. Он ждёт вашего развёрнутого ответа.

Comment: The first word actually might be like these ones)))

Comment: Or Japanese 日本語

Comment: @Leonid: может быть и так. Напишите ответ, изложите там свою точку зрения.

Answer (score 3):

Есть вот такой интересный вариант на jQuery.

*Выделяем первое слово в абзаце:*

```js
$("#first").html(function() {
  var text = $(this).text().trim().split(" ");
  var first = text.shift();
  return (text.length > 0 ? "<span class='active'>" + first + "</span> " : first) + text.join(" ");
});
```

```css
.active {color: red; font-weight: bold;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="first">Спорт приносит большую радость. Люди ходят в секции, посещают спорт – клубы, играют в спортивные игры, закаляются и общаются с новыми людьми. Спортивные командные игры приносят радость победы.</p>
```

*Выделяем последнее слово в абзаце:*

```js
$("#last").html(function() {
  var text = $(this).text().trim().split(" ");
  var last = text.pop();
  return text.join(" ") + (text.length > 0 ? " <span class='active'>" + last + "</span>" : last);
});
```

```css
.active {color: red; font-weight: bold;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="last">Спорт приносит большую радость. Люди ходят в секции, посещают спорт – клубы, играют в спортивные игры, закаляются и общаются с новыми людьми. Спортивные командные игры приносят радость победы.</p>
```